# phpUnit dataProvider - in the case of an error, the key of the dataprovider missing in result

Tags: phpunit

I have a simple "phpunit.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="autoload.php">
    <php>
        <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak" />
    </php>
        <testsuites>
            <testsuite name="SignIn Test Suite">
                <file>../vendor/item/signin-api-bundle/Tests/Controller/SignInControllerTest.php</file>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuites>
    </phpunit>
```

my Test:

```
class ControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideLoginMissing
     */
    public function testLoginMissing($requestData)
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('POST', '/login', array(), array(), array(), json_encode($requestData));
        static::assertContains('417', (string)$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }

    public function provideLoginMissing() {

        return [
            'testLoginAndUsernameMissing' => array(
                array(
                    'requestData' => array(
                        'loginData' => array(
                            'password' => 'TopSecret',
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),

            'testLoginAndPasswordMissing' => array(
                array(
                    'requestData' => array(
                        'loginData' => array(
                            'username' => 'Simon',
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ];
    }
}
```

and the result is

```
PHPUnit 5.6.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Failed asserting that '200' contains "417".
 ....\Controller.php:45


Time: 3.28 seconds, Memory: 8.50MB


FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.

Remaining deprecation notices (440)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

There is no information which dataprovider is not valid (testLoginAndUsernameMissing or testLoginAndPasswordMissing).
The list will be much longer in future, so I dont think I can use dataproviders. Its on older System (Symfony 2.8, PHPUnit 5.6) but I hope I can solve this problem. Is here some kind of additional configuration needed?

Thank you & Best Regards

Comment: It's pretty hard to say why this is failing without seeing the code you're testing. Is it possible that your data provider arrays are too deep? I.e. i see `'requestData'` array key in the data provider as well as the variable name in the unit test - perhaps you're confusing this and hence making the provided array two levels deeper than it needs to be (`'loginData'`?)

Comment: Re: "the list will be much longer in future, so i don't think I can use dataproviders" - why not? don't forget you can always pass callbacks to perform assertions from inside your dataprovider

Comment: Your testsuite is modified. PHPUnit normally shows a list of failiures in numbered form after the timings and before FAILURES! which contains the array key to identify the provided dataset w/ the failure. And perhaps not a feature of PHPUnit 4.1, just checking here against Phpunit 6.5.